# Bind data frames from two nested lists by list and df names

Tags: r, list, bind, nested-lists

I would like to bind R data frames from two different nested lists by its names as follows:

```
list1 = list(list_a = list(df1 = data.frame(letters = c('A','B','C'),
                                            numbers = seq(1,3)),
                           
                           df2 = data.frame(letters = c('A','B','C','D','E'),
                                            numbers = seq(1,5))),
             
             list_b = list(df3 = data.frame(norm = rnorm(4))))



list2 = list(list_a = list(df1 = data.frame(letters = c('D','E','F'),
                                            numbers = seq(4,6)),
                           
                           df2 = data.frame(letters = c('F','G','H','I','J'),
                                            numbers = seq(6,10))),
             
             list_b = list(df3 = data.frame(norm = rnorm(4))))
```

The result I expect after binding this two lists by names is:

```
> list3
$list_a
$list_a$df1
  letters numbers
1       A       1
2       B       2
3       C       3
4       D       4
5       E       5
6       F       6

$list_a$df2
   letters numbers
1        A       1
2        B       2
3        C       3
4        D       4
5        E       5
6        F       6
7        G       7
8        H       8
9        I       9
10       J      10


$list_b
$list_b$df3
        norm
1  0.1400504
2 -0.5785170
3 -0.2905891
4  1.9175712
5  1.8736454
6 -0.4895259
7  0.5975914
8  0.3586774
```

So, in brief what I really want to do is bind the respective data frame from this two nested list by its names.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that `list1` and `list2` have a mutual structure(identical depth, list names, order), you could use a nested `Map()`:

```r
Map(\(x, y) Map(rbind, x, y), list1, list2)
```

```
$list_a
$list_a$df1
  letters numbers
1       A       1
2       B       2
3       C       3
4       D       4
5       E       5
6       F       6

$list_a$df2
   letters numbers
1        A       1
2        B       2
3        C       3
4        D       4
5        E       5
6        F       6
7        G       7
8        H       8
9        I       9
10       J      10


$list_b
$list_b$df3
        norm
1  0.6370310
2  0.3425583
3 -0.8333353
4  1.5825106
5 -0.2551183
6  1.1983533
7 -1.0771730
8 -1.1065747
```

Comment: `tidyverse` alternative: `map2(list1, list2, ~ map2(.x, .y, bind_rows))`